# Update column with below query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, case

How do I write this query to update a column based on the case statement?

```
UPDATE Table
SET Form = CASE 
              WHEN (cnt - rownum < cnt % NumberUp) 
                 THEN 0 
                 ELSE  floor((rowNum - 1) / numberUp) + 1 
           END AS form
ORDER BY Quantity
```

Comment: Are `cnt` and `rownum` actual columns of the table?

Comment: yes they are columns in the table

Comment: It should work if you just remove `AS form
ORDER BY Quantity`

Comment: Just remove the `ORDER BY`, and your query looks fine.

Comment: Also the `AS form` does not make sense.

Comment: That worked, thank you! the snake would have bit me kinda situation.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you query looks pretty good, apart from these:

- the `ORDER BY` clause does not make sense; an `UPDATE` query does not return any record, so ordering is out of scope
- for the same reason, you don't have to alias the updated column

Consider:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Form = CASE 
    WHEN (cnt - rownum < cnt % NumberUp) THEN 0 
    ELSE  floor((rowNum - 1) / numberUp) + 1 
END
```